In a simple weighted planar graph, find the shortest (in terms of total length) set of closed walks that cover all shortest paths
Consider a simple planar graph $g$ embedded in the 2D plane with weights corresponding to Euclidean distances, and let $P$ be the set of all its shortest paths $p$.
I want to find a set $W$ of at most $M$ closed walks $w$. Combined, the walks within this set shall cover all paths from $P$. I want the total (weighted) length of all walks in $W$ to be minimal under those constraints.
Some clarification regarding my terminology:

I understand paths to be "directed". Thus, if we denote the single-edge path from node $ a$ to node $b$ as $(a,b)$, then $(a,b) \neq (b,a)$. This means that, if $g$ has $N$ nodes, $P$ will contain $N(N-1)$ distinct paths.
Closed walks are also "directed" in the same sense.
I do not care about the starting and ending nodes of the closed walks, so any cyclical permutation of their node sequence is equivalent. Thus, if we denote the triangular closed walk from node $a$ to $b$ to $c$ and back to $a$ as $\overline{(a,b,c)}$, then $\overline{(a,b,c)}=\overline{(b,c,a)}=\overline{(c,a,b)} \neq \overline{(a,c,b)}=\overline{(c,b,a)}=\overline{(b,a,c)}$.
With "covering", I mean that the (permuted) node sequence of the walk contains the node sequence of the path. For example: $(c,a) \subset \overline{(a,b,c)}$.

I have a rough idea for an algorithm:

reduce the set $P$ by removing all those paths which are sub-paths of other paths in $P$.
Consider all possible pairwise merges of paths from $P$. Based on some criterion, find the best merge and perform it. After each merge, repeat step 1.
If there are only a certain number of paths left in $P$ ($\leq M$? $\leq 2M$?), additionally consider closing paths into closed walks. This can be done by either merging two paths or by appending a shortest path at the end of an existing path.
If there are only closed walks left, check whether there are too many: If there are more than $M$, merge together existing closed walks until only $M$ remain.

The critical part here is the criterion for the merging decisions.
If this algorithm seems reasonable, what would be a good criterion?
Or, if the algorithm is flawed somehow: What would be a better way?
Maybe constructing the closed walks edge by edge?
If there are reasons to believe that it's impossible to find the optimal solution without a brute force search (which I wouldn't even be sure how to implement), I'd also be happy about a "close enough" solution.
